# Integration of a generic radial function in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, polar-coordinates, bessel-functions

I need to perform the following integral

$\int{P(k) e^{i \vec{k}\cdot \vec{\Delta r}} \frac{d^2k}{(2 \pi) ^2}}$

using polar coordinates. I think the result should depend on some Bessel function, but I don't know how to proceed to show that. The form of $P(k)$ is, in principle, a generic function dependent only on the modulus $k$.

EDIT:

I think I was able to arrive to the following form, using polar coordinates where the axis is oriented along the vector $\vec{\Delta r}$.

$ \int{ P(\rho) e^{-i \rho \Delta r cos \theta }\rho  d\rho  d\theta}$

But then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You lost a factor of $2\pi$ in going from the first integral to the second. Only one of them should be cancelled by the Jacobian. In the second form, the integral over $\theta$ can be carried out explicitly, using integration by parts. What remains is an integral over $\rho$, which of course can't be carried out without knowing $P$.

Comment: You are right when you say that I lost the $2 \pi$ factors, but I think I lost both of them: I don't see why one should be cancelled by the Jacobian. Isn't it $d k_x d k_y = k d k d \theta$?

Comment: You're right of course, sorry -- I confused it with the factor of $2\pi$ you get when you integrate out $\theta$ and the integrand doesn't depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use method, which is used in the calculation of [Green function of wave equation](http://www.sbfisica.org.br/rbef/pdf/351304.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, so do you agree that the result should be $ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int{ P(\rho) J_0 (\rho \Delta r) \rho d \rho}$?

Comment: Yes. Of course, if all used integrals exists and if we can use Fubini theorem.